# i'm getting compile time-error when i create class public why?

Tags: java

```
public class foo{int a;}
public class foo2{public static void main(String[] a){System.out.println("love");}}
```

The error is:

> C:\Users\PUSHPAM\Desktop\java>javac foo2.java foo2.java:1: error: class foo is public, should be declared in a file named foo.java public class foo{

Comment: The actual file name in which your code is defined must be foo.java. Based on your command, you named the file foo2.java instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one `public` class per Java source file. The name of that file must match the public class name, so if you have a public class called `MyClass`, it must be in a file called `MyClass.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you have multiple classes in single program then you have to save your class with the class which have `main()` method. And that class should be **public** type. Don't make all the classes as public in one file.

**Example:**

```
class Vehicle {
    //something
}

class Audi {
    //something
}

class Manager {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      // something
     }
}
```

`main()` method is available in Class **Manager**. Because of this i have to save the file with `Manager.java`.

> javac Manager.java ---- .class files will generate for all the classes
>
> java Manager --- getting output